# Why does innodb lock more records when range deletion

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using mysql innodb database. I thought I had understood the locking mechanism of mysql. But I found an example, which conflicts with my understanding.See the example below (verified in version 5.7.32 with rc isolation level).

create table

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `ep` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `e_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `update_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_e_id` (`e_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_create_at` (`create_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

initial data

```
insert into ep(e_id, name, create_at) values(100, 'shijie', '2022-12-01 00:00:00'),(100, 'jianfeng', '2022-12-02 00:00:00'),(100, 'syx', '2022-12-03 00:00:00');
```

Before the next case testing, there are 3 records in the ep table.

```
 id: 1
 e_id: 100
 name: shijie
 create_at: 2022-12-01 00:00:00
 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13

 id: 2
 e_id: 100
 name: jianfeng
 create_at: 2022-12-02 00:00:00
 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13

 id: 3
 e_id: 100
 name: syx
 create_at: 2022-12-03 00:00:00
 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13
```

- test case 1

concurrent transactions

| Session1 | Session2 | Locks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| begin; | begin; |  |
| insert into ep(e_id, name, create_at) values(100, 'stt', '2022-12-04 00:00:00'); |  |  |
|  | insert into ep(e_id, name, create_at) values(100, 'ssd', '2022-12-04 00:00:00'); |  |
| select * from ep\G; id: 1 e_id: 100 name: shijie create_at: 2022-12-01 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 2 e_id: 100 name: jianfeng create_at: 2022-12-02 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 3 e_id: 100 name: syx create_at: 2022-12-03 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 4 e_id: 100 name: stt create_at: 2022-12-04 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:41:47 | select * from ep\G; id: 1 e_id: 100 name: shijie create_at: 2022-12-01 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 2 e_id: 100 name: jianfeng create_at: 2022-12-02 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 3 e_id: 100 name: syx create_at: 2022-12-03 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 5 e_id: 100 name: ssd create_at: 2022-12-04 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:44:46 |  |
| delete from ep where e_id=100 and create_at <= '2022-12-03 00:00:00'; |  | lock waiting |

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDOpd.png)

- test case 2

concurrent transactions

| Session1 | Session2 | Locks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| begin; | begin; |  |
| insert into ep(e_id, name, create_at) values(100, 'stt', '2022-12-04 00:00:00'); |  |  |
|  | insert into ep(e_id, name, create_at) values(100, 'ssd', '2022-12-04 00:00:00'); |  |
| select * from ep\G; id: 1 e_id: 100 name: shijie create_at: 2022-12-01 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 2 e_id: 100 name: jianfeng create_at: 2022-12-02 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 3 e_id: 100 name: syx create_at: 2022-12-03 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 4 e_id: 100 name: stt create_at: 2022-12-04 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:41:47 | select * from ep\G; id: 1 e_id: 100 name: shijie create_at: 2022-12-01 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 2 e_id: 100 name: jianfeng create_at: 2022-12-02 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 3 e_id: 100 name: syx create_at: 2022-12-03 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:31:13 id: 5 e_id: 100 name: ssd create_at: 2022-12-04 00:00:00 update_at: 2023-01-01 05:44:46 |  |
| delete from ep where e_id=100 and create_at <= '2022-12-02 00:00:00'; |  | no lock waiting |

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYMw6.png)

- expectation

In my understanding, when deleting according to e_id and create_at, the data will be locked in the following steps.

Step 1: find ids with e_id=100(get ids 1,2,3,4,5)

Step 2: find ids with create_at <= '2022-12-03 00:00:00''(get ids 1,2,3)

Step 3: get the intersection of the result ids of step 1 and step 2(get ids 1,2,3)

Step 4: lock on ids 1, 2 and 3

The order of steps 1 and 2 can be reversed.
So test case 2 is what I expected.

- question

In test case 1, when the deletion range of create_at is large, session1 tries to acquire the primary key lock of session2 inserting data(id=5). In fact, the data inserted in session2 is out of the deletion range of create_at in session1.

In test case 2, reduce the deletion range of create_at(2022-12-03 00:00:00 -> 2022-12-02 00:00:00), and session 1 will no longer acquire any locks of the data inserted by session 2(neither the primary key lock nor the secondary index lock).

In fact, when deleting according to the primary key index range, such as `delete from ep where id <= id_num`, there also has the problem of large-scale deletion to obtain more lock inserted by other concurrent sessions and small-scale deletion not to obtain more lock.

Can anyone explain the cause of this problem or provide related articles.

Comment: What rows exist before, between, after the rows you are inserting/deleting?  This may be a "gap" lock.  Also, provide `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added log of existing rows before, between, after the rows i am inserting/deleting. And if you click on the word `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS OUTPUT` in the text, you can view detailed lock information.<br>In these two test cases, there is no gap lock, only record lock(rec but not gap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL locks the rows it looks at during execution (and potentially frees them again).

In your case, based on the behaviour, for the second test case, MySQL uses the index on `create_at` to find the rows, for the first case, it doesn't.

So for your second delete, MySQL will not even look at ids 4 and 5 (because they are outside of the date range), and thus doesn't have to wait for locks on ids 4 and 5.

For your first delete, MySQL doesn't use the index, but either the primary key or the index on `e_id`, and thus has to wait for the lock.

Repeat the experiment without the index, and it might match your understanding (although you didn't actually specify what you did expect).

Comment: I have added my expectations in the text.
After reading your reply, I fully understand the reasons for the above two cases.
I misunderstood the locking rules of mysql innodb.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Answer, but useful info...)

Replace `idx_e_id` with

```
INDEX(e_id, created_at)
```

So that there will be a useful index for the `DELETE`.

Comment: Sorry, although it is a solution to the actual problem, it does not explain the reasons for my above two cases.